# How to Override the Popup Snooze and Dismiss button in alarm notification

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is it possible override the popup of snooze and dismiss button or to write some code in the Snooze or Dismiss button which navigate to other page?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to override these buttons for an alarm. 
But if you are going to use a reminder then you can specify a relative navigation URI and when an user taps by a reminder pop up, he will be redirected to your app directly to specified URI. This works for reminders, not for alarms. More details are here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202946(v=vs.105).aspx.

Comment: thanks but The page link you given cannot be found. Can you have other sample please

Comment: Try again, pls. I've fixed the link.

Comment: Can we change the snooze and dismiss button events.Like these buttons works when a variable has some value.

Comment: No, there is no way to implement it with current API.